# FFmpeg | Option loop not found

Tags: ffmpeg

The loop option is not working with gif image.
When I'm working with png image the code good.
But when I'm working with animated gif image the error is thrown `Option loop not found`.

In my example I'm trying to create the video from input image with specific duration.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i 15324210315b56e3a78abe5.png -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[v];[v][1]overlay=x=(W-w-10):y=(H-h-10)" output.mp4
```

Below command is not working

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i 15323488345b55c9a2b2908.gif -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[v];[v][1]overlay=x=(W-w-10):y=(H-h-10)" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GIFs are handled by a seperate demuxer module, not the generic image sequence demuxer. The gif demuxer has a separate option. See command below.

```
ffmpeg -ignore_loop 0 -t 5 -i 15323488345b55c9a2b2908.gif ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The python script for gif to video conversion using ffmpeg library

```js
f"/opt/ffmpeglib/ffmpeg -ignore_loop 0 -i {lambda_file_path} -c:v libx264 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p {lambda_output_file_path}
```